# How to solve for the area of the composite figure.

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

I don't understand how I will solve for the area of the figure on no. 7. it seems the given information is not enough.

[image]

Comment: It looks like this came from the same source as your previous question, which was underdetermined. This one is also under-determined (unless you make some assumptions like right angles).

Comment: I guess your question is wrong as we don't know where each and every point is actually in the plane and also please please add your approach in your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try joining the left and right parts to make a square

Also the height of the rectangle is the length of diagonal of the square $-2(1.1)$

Comment: so the height of the rectangle is $9.4\sqrt 2 - 2.2 ≈11.09$?

Comment: but the figure does not say whether the angle of the tip of the arrows are 90°

Comment: @harpey1111 is there an indication about that somewhere earlier in the problem?